# How can I cut a word under cursor in Vim?

Tags: vim

I usually want to cut the word under cursor and paste it somewhere else, is there any existing command can do this?

For example, if the cursor is under `x` in `AA BXB CC DD`, the result should be `AA  CC DD` while `BXB` is copied to system clipboard.

Comment: yup. added an ELI5 example to add "clarity".

Comment: to answer the question, in case you mapped `d` to not copy text when deleting, you can use `viwx` to highlight and cut the word under the cursor.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Type `diw`

This means delete in word.

Related commands:

- To copy: `yiw`
- To cut: `ciw`

Comment: `ciw` actually cuts the word and then puts you into insert mode. `yiw` would copy the word.

Comment: `diW ` for deleting word where a word separator is considered to be only a space.  So this will delete "words" with non alpha-numeric chars such as '/' etc

Comment: `ciw` stands for "change in word", not for "cut". In fact, it puts you in insert mode, so you can "change" what was written before. The command `diw` is the right answer.